# Simple C pointer program, not running

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

I have the following simple c program I am trying to run in CLion but is telling me that my char needs to be a pointer which I already have set as a pointer and declared to array abc so I am not sure what the issue is or how to debug it! The code was initially a sample for a lecture and I added the pointer declaration to see what happens when I run it. Any help would be appreciate.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    char *a;
    char abc[5];
    a = abc;
    int i = 0;

    while (1 == scanf("/%[^/ \t\n]", a[i++]))
        printf(">%s<\n", a[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but you are *indexing* that pointer, so you are passing a `char` to `scanf`.

Comment: scanf waits a pointer, `a[i++]` is not a pointer. `&a[i++]`

Comment: ... and with an array length of only `5` it is quite likely you will break its limits. Suggest testing with `char abc[500];` initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though `a` is a pointer, `a[i++]` is not. In general, `a[x]` is equivalent to `*(a + x)`, so in your case it is as if you had `*(a + i++)`, where the `*` dereferences the pointer. You can use either `&a[i++]` to turn it back into a pointer, or `a + i++`.

Comment: @Nuggets10 I'm glad it was helpful. Other than what you asked, please note the comment from Weather Vane, which raises a very valid point: `abc[5]` can hold only 4 characters of input + the NUL terminator, so you are very likely to overrun it as you don't limit the input length in your `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` needs a pointer to put the scanned result into. This is because in C arguments are passed by value so cannot be written to in a way the caller will see. We get around that by passing a pointer to the original variable, the called function can then write to the original variable directly in a way the caller will see. Try changing:

```
while (1 == scanf("/%[^/ \t\n]", a[i++]))
```

into

```
while (1 == scanf("/%[^/ \t\n]", a + i++))
```

Comment: Even pointers cannot be written to in a way the caller will see ;-). (The memory they *point to* can be written to though, and that write can be observed by any part of the program that has access to that memory.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Yeah, that is indeed correct. I was trying to prioritize keeping it simple over being specific, but I will try and clarify it slightly, thanks.